# How to get extension file in Nutgram?

Tags: php

I use this code to get file in [Nutgram](https://nutgram.dev/docs/introduction):

```
 $file = $bot->getFile($fileId);
 $uniqueFileName = uniqid();
 $bot->downloadFile($file, 'reports');
```

How to get  extension file and name?

I have tried to parse file_path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using file_path in $file as follows.

```php
// Get the file extension
function getFileExtension ( string $fileName ): string
{
   return '.' . strtolower(pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
}
```